# sql Find data that does NOT exist in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to find all records that do **not** match my criteria.

I have a one-to-many table  where for each key combo (wbs1, wbs2, wbs3) there may be many records.  I'm trying to query this table for each combo, and return the combo (wbs1, wbs2, wbs3) only when the table has no records that match my "in" criteria.

But at the moment, my query seems to be returning all or nothing.

```
select distinct wbs1, wbs2, wbs3
     from dbo.Registry
     where not exists ( select wbs1, wbs2, wbs3, InspType
                        from Registry
                        where ISNULL(InspType,'') IN ('Test 1','Test 2')
                       )
```

What I'd like in the return is a list of wbs1,wbs2,wbs3 where in the table "Registry" there are no entries that match the Test (InspType) criteria.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close, and the subquery likely isn't even necessary, but this modification should get you the correct results. But as-written, you need a way to refer to the outer query, thus the `dbo.Registry r` alias.

```
select distinct wbs1, wbs2, wbs3
     from dbo.Registry r
     where not exists ( select 1
                        from Registry
                        where ISNULL(InspType,'') IN ('Test 1','Test 2')
                        and (wbs1 = r.wbs1 or wbs2 = r.wbs2 or wbs3 = r.wbs3)
                       )
```

This is assuming Microsoft Sql Server of some flavor, so I don't know if it'd work in MySql or Oracle or whatever.

But couldn't you also just do

```
select distinct wbs1, wbs2, wbs3
from dbo.Registry
where ISNULL(InspType, '') != 'Test 1'
and ISNULL(InspType, '') != 'Test 2'
```

and avoid the subquery entirely?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find wbs1, wbs2, wbs3 combo when there is nothing in the registry that matches. There are a lot of instances in the registry where InspType != Test 1 or Test 2. And I actually don't want them in return. I just want to know the case when Test 1 and Test 2 don't exist for that combo.

Comment: Oh, this is a bit ugly, but maybe this [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7aa1c/13) will do the trick in your case.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. The alias/reference was exactly what I was missing. I couldn't remember how to connect the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a "set-within-sets" subquery, which I like solving with aggregation and logic in the `having` clause.  The following will return all combinations that are missing one or both tests:

```
select wbs1, wbs2, wbs3
from dbo.Registry r
group by wbs1, wbs2, wbs3
having sum(case when InspType = 'Test 1' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when InspType = 'Test 2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: I tried this, and I'm still getting records that have an InspType of Test 1 and Test 2. The "having" statement doesn't seem to be excluding these records?

Comment: Change the "or" to an "AND" or combine both into a single CASE: having sum(case when InspType in ('Test 1','Test 2') then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: @GabeN. . . . The query could be returning records that have one of the values but not both.